# iAd : ADInternalErrorCode 5 (not 3)

Tags: iphone, iad

I'm facing some strange issue with iAd. My app is fine in the simulator, but in the device, I get many iAd errors with ADInternalErrorCode = 5 which means "Banner view is visible but does not have content".

It is different from the error 3 which occurs when no ad is available.

I'm not using AdWhirl, it's just an ADBannerView.

What does mean this error?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to occur because the ADBannerView isn't off the screen before receiving any ad (or fail).